# Auto Pop Up Save As Window For Firefox

Tags: html, popup

I've been using this code `<a href="FILEPATH">download PDF</a>` to directly download a link for pdf but this code only work in Google Chrome

Can someone help me to make this work in Mozilla Firefox and IE8 as well. Because when I try to test it in Mozilla Firefox it opens the links but doesn't pop up the "Save As" window.

Comment: Do you need it to be `HTML5` or do you have server-side code you can hit? I usually use headers for my downloads

Comment: You want a `Content-Disposition: attachment` response header. You can also add a `Download` attribute on the `A` tag, which works in Firefox and Chrome but not IE.

Comment: @EricLaw I already tried putting a download attribute after the file path but still this only works for Google Chrome but in Mozilla Firefox it opens the link on same window

Comment: I don't know what "after the filepath" means. Firefox 20+ is supposed to support the `Download` attribute, per http://caniuse.com/download Did you add the Content-Disposition: attachment header?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use PHP headers so reference the file with something like this for the url:

```
 <a href="/download.php?file=myFile.pdf">download PDF</a>
```

Then use php to deliver the file:

```
 <?php
 /* put some validation and injection protection here */
 $approvedFiles = ["myFile.pdf","myOtherFile.pdf"];

 if (!in_array($_GET['file'],$approvedFiles)){
  header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); 
  die();
 }

 //otherwise
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myFile.pdf"');
 readfile('myFile.pdf');
```

Note: pseudo code is not perfect :)

Refs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/RemMp/

```
<a id="save_data" href="">link</a>

window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;
var a = document.getElementById('save_data');

var data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVQImWNgYGBgAAAABQABh6FO1AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
var filename = 'qqq.pdf';

a.download = filename;
a.href = data;
a.textContent = 'Downloading...';

//release memory
a.onclick = function(e){
    save_cleanup(this);
    };
//force click
document.querySelector('#save_data').click();

function save_cleanup(a){
    a.textContent = 'Downloaded';
    setTimeout(function(){
        a.href = '';
        var element = document.getElementById("save_data");
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }, 1500);
    };
```

Comment: yes, this is html5 version that does not require server, but require new browser with a[download] support. http://caniuse.com/download